# Changing color of text in a WPF RichTextBox from a different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, dispatcher

This is probably a really easy question, so sorry in advance if there are duplicates, but I haven't found anything about this specific problem yet.

I have a problem with coloring specific parts of text in a RichTextBox from a different thread. I want to append a line of text to the RichTextBox and at the same time color that line with a specified color. I was able to append text and color it, but haven't been able to do so from another thread, although I was able to append plain text from the Dispatcher.

Here is my code:

```
private void UpdateTextbox(string message, Brush color)
{
    rtbOutput.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            rtbOutput.Selection.Select(rtbOutput.Document.ContentEnd, rtbOutput.Document.ContentEnd);
            rtbOutput.Selection.Text = message;
            rtbOutput.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, color);
        })
    );
}
```

When I try running it from another thread I get an error message telling me the object can't be accessed, because it belongs to another thread. How do I solve this?

Edit: Seems like the RichTextBox isn't the problem, but the Brush object is, because I can change the color just fine if I specify it inside the Invoke method, but not if I pass it as a parameter.

Comment: UI objects can only be updated by the UI thread. If you're using Tasks, you can use `task.ContinueWith(() => { // code here }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push the actual change work back on to the GUI thread. During the startup of your application, you can run:

`SynchronizationContext ctxt = SynchronizationContext.Current;` and then pass that somewhere your multithreaded code can get at it. Then to use it:

```
//Code that determines the color to use

Color clr = result;

ctxt.Send((clr_obj) =>
{
//Code to set color
}, clr);
```

Edit:

Here is a nice article that explains `SyncronizationContext` much more in depth: [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I)

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I get the same error message on the ApplyPropertyValue function. I'm using the SynchronizationContext like this:

uiContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(
                delegate(object state)
    {
        // operations on Richtextbox
    }), null);

Should I use it differently?

Comment: You don't need to use a delegate at that point. You can just call the methods normally. Just place everything inside your dispatcher in there.

Comment: also I just edited my answer with an article on the class from codeplex

Comment: Got it working now. Turned out my code had a different problem than I thought. But your answer works too and thanks for the article, it was very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it wasn't the RichTextBox that was owned by another thread, but the Brush object. I managed to get it to work with all the solutions down below, if I just pass a Color object to the method instead and convert it to a SolidColorBrush inside the Dispatcher.

```
private void UpdateTextbox(string message, Color color)
{
    rtbOutput.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            TextRange range = new TextRange(rtbOutput.Document.ContentEnd, rtbOutput.Document.ContentEnd);
            range.Text = message;
            range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush((Color)color));
        })
    );
}
```

It also works with this code suggested by pquest:

```
private void UpdateTextbox(string message, Brush color)
{
    uiContext.Send(o =>
        {
            TextRange range = new TextRange(rtbOutput.Document.ContentEnd, rtbOutput.Document.ContentEnd);
            range.Text = message;
            range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, color);
        }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track using Dispatcher, but you don't always need to call Invoke.  I use the following extension method to handle this type of thing:

```
    public static void InvokeIfNeeded(this Dispatcher dispatcher, Action action)
    {
        if (dispatcher == null || dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            action();
        else
            dispatcher.Invoke(action, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    }
```

You would use it as follows:

```
private void UpdateTextbox(string message, Brush Color)
{
    rtbOutput.Dispatcher.InvokeIfNeeded(() =>
        {
            rtbOutput.Selection.Select(rtbOutput.Document.ContentEnd, rtbOutput.Document.ContentEnd);
            rtbOutput.Selection.Text = message;
            rtbOutput.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Color);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: This is useful, but it doesn't change my problem of not being able to access the ApplyPropertyValue function even from within the Dispatcher.

Comment: If you're creating rtbOutput on the UI thread, this should work for you.

Comment: You are right, your method works. It just didn't solve my problem, because I was looking for a solution at the wrong place.